# EJB How to use EntityManager with CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, ejb, apache-tomee

I have to make a call to an external REST-Interface for a status that should be saved into the DB. Since it could take some time till the REST-Ressource is available I wish to keep this in a seperate thread.

My current Idea is to use a CompletableFuture like this:

```
@PersistenceContext 
EntityManager entityManager;
StatusEntity statusEntity;

public void updateDBStatus(String statusId){
      CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> getRestStatus(statusId))
            .thenAccept((String result)-> persistResult(result));
}
private void persistResult(String result){
      statusEntity = new StatusEntity();
      statusEntity.setStatus(result);
      //Debugger just stops here
      entityManager.persist(statusEntity);
}
```

When I try to debug I just get stuck at the "entityManager.persist"-Line without any other error message. Is the problem because the EJB keeps the EnityManager only on the main-thread? How can I use the entityManager in my completableFuture?

Comment: What is your server platform? You cannot use EJBs in Tomcat, unless it is actually TomEE

Comment: I'm using TomEE but that was not an option for the tag. Currently I'm thinking of just using @Asynchronous on methods with return value of completable future and then chain them, would that make sense?